# Searching for selected checked list box item in database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm creating a meeting planner program in c#, I've populated the checked list box with the first names and last names  from the database.

However i want to understand how I'd be able to check which users were selected to be added so i can add their userID to a separate database. Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm pretty new to using sql in c#.

Code:

```
ds.Tables.Add(cms.GettingUserTable());

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        cblUser.Items.Add(item["FirstName"] + " " + item["LastName"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: the checkbox list items will have a `checked` value I think

Comment: Side note: `$"{item["FirstName"]} {item["LastName"]}"` (string interpolation) is by far *more readable* than `item["FirstName"] + " " + item["LastName"].ToString()`

Comment: I know about the checked value, i just wasn't sure how to then get the separated values of the FirstName and LastName that have been combined to then be used in a query for the relevant UserID's

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it is your opinion, I find interpolation less readable in this case as it is much deeper nested. Subjective readability is affected by code you are used to work with.

Comment: Make use of the “Tag” property.
It takes in an object, it can be anything, so you could store in there the entire person object or just the id.

Before adding in the item populate its Tag property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it: create a list when populating the check box list using the UserID. Convert the list into an array then match the array index with the checked box index

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us how you get your Values from SQL server.

I had the same Problem, but i am using a method that takes all data form sql server as `ObservableCollection`

My example method, maybe would help you

```
 public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProduct(int supplierId)
    {
        var listProdukt = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        using (var sqlConnection = OpenSqlConnection())
        {
            var sqlCommandText = $"SELECT "something..."};";
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = sqlCommandText,
                Connection = sqlConnection
            };

            var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var product = new Product
                    {
                        ProductSizeBySupplierId = int.Parse(reader["ProductSizeBySupplierId"].ToString()),
                        CategoryId = int.Parse(reader["CategoryId"].ToString()),                          
                    };
                    listProdukt.Add(product);
                }
            }
        }

        return listProdukt;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share it plaese

Comment: I obtain the values using a function in a separate content management class

    `public DataTable GettingUserTable()
        {
           string Query = "Select * from Users";
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectionString.GetConnection());
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           SqlDataAdapter sds = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);
            sds.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

"However i want to understand how I'd be able to check which users were selected to be added so i can add their userID to a separate database."

What you could do is to:

Lets say you have a table like

```
Planner_Table
---------------------------------------
|Id | First_Name | Last_Name | Checked |
---------------------------------------
```

Then you can look for entries in your database with (if you only want checked entries):

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Planner_Table WHERE [Checked] = true
```

Then modify your code:

```
cblUser.Items.Add(item["FirstName"] + " " + item["LastName"] + " " + item["Checked"]);
```